# AWS Route53 A record to external ip, Certificate is Ineligible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-route53

I have an A record with my subdomain `hello.example.com`.
It points to an external IP address.

The web server runs behind that IP address returns an SSL certificate.
But the browser does not trust it.

Also, I created a certificate in ACM with the subdomain and the status was successful but it is not in use and ineligible.

Comment: ACM is used only with AWS managed services (CloudFront, API Gateway, Elastic Loadbalancer,..). So you may put the server in a private subnet behind a load balancer. Or use a proper certificate (e. g. Letsencrypt is free too)

Comment: Thanks for reply. The server does not belong to us, they are just a partner. So that's not the solution.

Comment: Then your partner need to do that properly (return a valid certificate). You cannot do that for a 3rd party server. DNS A record is just a pointer to an IP address. It is a responsibility of the server to return a valid certificate.

Comment: The reason why the browser invalidates the certificate is that the origin name and the certificate CA name is not matching, right?

IS it somehow possible they could add our subdomain name to CA name?

Comment: CN or AlternateSubjectName must much the url hostname. You cannot just add a subdomain, a new certificate needs to be provided (or using a wildcard certificate)

Comment: Thank you very much. I think my case is pretty obvious. I am trying to make a secure connection between a 3th party web server that I don't have any control and my subdomain via an A record. This case is exactly what SSL blocks right? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recapitulation as an answer

> server runs behind that IP address returns an SSL certificate.. I created a certificate in ACM with the subdomain

ACM is used only with AWS managed services (CloudFront, API Gateway, Elastic Loadbalancer,..). So you may put the server in a private subnet behind a load balancer.

You cannot do that for a 3rd party server. DNS A record is just a pointer to an IP address. It is a responsibility of the server to return a valid certificate.

> I am trying to make a secure connection between a 3th party web server that I don't have any control and my subdomain via an A record.

The server SSL certificates are intended to make sure the client communicates with the right server. The server needs to prove its domain name with the certificate when establishing the SSL connection.

Imagine you create your own DNS record pointing to any 3rd party site e. g. amazon site and you cannot expect it working.

Edit: it may be working if the server is using a wildcard certificate. Example - the server could use a certificate `CN=*.example.com` then a subdomain `mysite.example.com` would be trusted as well